# Powershell syntax highlighting overwrites foreground colour

Tags: command-line, powershell, colors

I'm trying to set the colours of my powershell window. In particular, I often have a few different windows open for different purposes, and I want to use the font colour to easily differentiate between them (I have a setup script for each purpose, in which I want to set the colour).

I try to do this with commands like
`$host.ui.rawui.ForegroundColor = "Blue"`
When I run this, the prompt correctly changes colour, and if I hit enter a few times, the new lines have the same colour. However, if I send a command (like `ls`) or even enter some text and then remove it and press enter, the colour reverts back to its original colour:
[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W48By.png)
(the last colour change is me entering text, deleting it and then pressing enter)

Given that the change seems to happen when I enter text, I'm guessing it is the syntax highlighting that is the problem. Whenever the highlighting is invoked, the new colour goes away. Indeed, if I use `Remove-Module psreadline`, I do not have this problem (I understand psreadline handles the syntax highlighting).

What is the solution here?

- Removing psreadline and all associated functionality? (anyone know how to add items to the shell command history without psreadline?)
- Disable syntax highlighting some other way? (Can't find a way to do this, only tips about changing all the highlight colours to the same colour, which would not fix my problem. Not having the highlighting is ok)
- Interrupt PS every time a command is sent and reset the colour (seems hacky. Also, how?)
- Tell psreadline to reset the colour to the current colour (blue) rather than the default (grey)? (How?)
- Update the default colour (so that it gets reverted to blue)? (How do I do this in a way that can be different for different windows without having to set it manually every time?)
- Live with grey text and admit defeat?

Example:

```
PS C:\> $console.ForegroundColor = "blue"; $console.ForegroundColor
Blue
PS C:\> $console.ForegroundColor
Gray
```

Comment: @DavidPostill's answer should work and you may also want to look into [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), as it's far more customizable than the default Windows terminals _(custom ConEmu [`config.xml`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/ConEmu/ConEmu.xml) and other ways to [customize](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/Powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1) `Set-Prompt` colors)_

Answer (score 1):

#### Tell psreadline to reset the colour to the current colour (blue) rather than the default (grey)?

Try adding the following to your `profile.ps1`

```
$options = Get-PSReadlineOption
$options.CommandColor = "blue"
$options.KeywordColor = "blue"
$options.NumberColor = "blue"
$options.MemberColor = "blue"
$options.VariableColor = "blue"
```

Here is mine for reference:

```
$console = $host.UI.RawUI
$console.ForegroundColor = "black"
$console.BackgroundColor = "white"

$buffer = $console.BufferSize
$buffer.Width = 200
$buffer.Height = 2000
$console.BufferSize = $buffer

$size = $console.WindowSize
$size.Width = 200
$size.Height = 60
$console.WindowSize = $size

$colors = $host.PrivateData
$colors.VerboseForegroundColor = "blue"
$colors.VerboseBackgroundColor = "white"
$colors.WarningForegroundColor = "yellow"
$colors.WarningBackgroundColor = "white"
$colors.ErrorForegroundColor = "red"
$colors.ErrorBackgroundColor = "white"

Import-Module AudioDeviceCmdlets
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

$env:Path = "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apps\WSCC\Sysinternals Suite;C:\apps\WSCC\NirSoft Utilities";

Function Prompt {
    $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = Get-Location
    "> "
}

$options = Get-PSReadlineOption
$options.CommandColor = "black"
$options.KeywordColor = "black"
$options.NumberColor = "black"
$options.MemberColor = "black"
$options.VariableColor = "black"

# display version
# write-host "Version: " -noNewLine | get-host | select-object version | format-table -hideTableHeaders
write-host "Version: " -noNewLine | get-host | select version | ft -hideTableHeaders
chcp 65001 | out-null
```

Comment: This only sets the command line to blue. I want the entire shell/console/window/whateveryoucallit to be blue.

Comment: `$console.ForegroundColor = "blue"`?

Comment: Works well, until I do anything that invokes the syntax highlighting. 
(I added an example of this at the end of the original post)

Comment: Well my settings work fine (with black instead of blue).

Comment: Mixing different foreground colours seems to be your issue.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to fix that? Is there anything I can do to tell PSReadLine to look for a different colour?

Comment: I've no idea what you are doing incorrectly but I can't repro your issue

Comment: What is in your `profile.ps1`? And what exactly are you doing once the window is open?

Comment: Please include 2 of your "setup scripts" in the question.

Comment: All I have in my profile is ```Set-Alias -Name vi -Value vim```. I get this effect even without using the setup scripts, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Then I've no more ideas.